# C# Call an object from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to program a small game where there are a few barriers that you have to jump over, go under and so on. Now, for that i can move the barriers and jump at the same time, I opened a new thread. This is in the Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Worker workerObject;
    Thread workerThread;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        workerObject = new Worker();
        workerObject.Form1 = this;
        workerObject.initialize(this);
        workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.DoWork);

    }
```

And:

```
public class Worker
{
    private volatile bool _shouldStop = false;
    public volatile Form Form1;
    public void initialize(Form pForm)
    {
        Form1 = pForm;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            _shouldStop = true;
            picture_barrier1.Left = picture_barrier1.Left - 1;
        }
    }

    public void RequestStop()
    {
        _shouldStop = true;
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Error 1   Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'Game.Form1'
>   via nested type 'Game.Form1.Worker'

Then when I go into the Form1.Designer.cs and make the barriers static (By the way, the objects are volatile), I get 11 errors from the code above containing:

> Error 1   Member 'Game.Form1.picture_barrier1' cannot be accessed with
>   an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

How do I call those objects correctly from another thread?

Comment: just because worker is nested inside Form class it does not inherit the isntance memeber of Form class.......Pass instance of Form class in worker class

Comment: Side note: you will encounter painful problems trying to use threads with WinForm controls... You may want to consider Timers instead. Especially if delegates and instance/static methods are confusing for you.

Comment: you already have form1 instance of Form in your worker class.....change code like this form1.picture_barrier1.Left = form1.picture_barrier1.Left - 1;

Comment: Modifying the designer.cs is strongly not recommend, it's very easy to mess up with the UI controls

Comment: shouldStop = true, you are not allowed to access UI properties on a worker thread.  Like Left.  You did not get this far yet, stop before you shoot your leg off.